# libnss3 and network-manager and Private Internet Access VPN

Tags: networking, network-manager, vpn, openvpn

I installed the new security update for libnss3 released today.

https://www.ubuntu.com/usn/usn-3336-1/

I use network-manager w/ gnome to connect to PIA's VPN

https://www.privateinternetaccess.com/pages/client-support/ubuntu-openvpn

It won't connect anymore since I updated libnss3. It's like it timeouts.

A typical OpenVPN file it uses looks like:

```
[connection]
id=[some name of some server]
uuid=[some uuid]
type=vpn
autoconnect=false

[vpn]
service-type=org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.openvpn
username=[some username]
comp-lzo=yes
remote=[some server].privateinternetaccess.com
cipher=AES-256-CBC
auth=SHA256
connection-type=password
password-flags=1
port=1197
proto-tcp=no
ca=/etc/openvpn/pia-ca.rsa.4096.crt

[ipv4]
method=auto
```

If I downgrade libnss3 to its last version, everything works. I'd really like to not have to downgrade something like a network security library though.

Comment: Have you asked PIA if this is because they haven't updated their OpenVPN infrastructure?  Because my OpenVPN servers all still function even with the latest `libnss3` updates, and they all run on pfSense-backed systems for OpenVPN.

Comment: Also, unrelated, `libnss3` and OpenVPN don't even interact at all - OpenVPN doesn't use `libnss3`, so the fact that update broke OpenVPN for you is a 'coincidence' and not actually a fact, according to my contact on the Security team